# Can't connect to SSRS in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm using [SSRS SDK for PHP](https://ssrsphp.codeplex.com/)

PHP Version 5.4

webserver: Centos 6.4

MSSQL Server 2008 R2

```
define("UID", "*****\*****");
define("PASWD", "*****");
define("SERVICE_URL", "http://192.168.0.1/ReportServerURL/");
try {
  $ssrs_report = new SSRSReport(new Credentials(UID, PASWD), SERVICE_URL);
} catch (SSRSReportException $serviceException) {
  echo $serviceException->GetErrorMessage() . "<br>";
}
```

When I try to connect SSRS report, it is throughing the following error:

`Failed to connect to Reporting Service
Make sure that the url (http://192.168.0.1/ReportServerURL/) and credentials are correct!`

The same credentials & link are accessible through browser without problem. But, through SSRS SDK it is not working.

I was looking for a solution in the net and I find that using the file `TestSSRSConnection.php` I could get more details but I dont know how to use it, and I cant find any documentation about it.

```
$testSSRSConnection = new TestSSRSConnection("/192.168.0.1/TESTREPORT/ReportServerURL/*****\*****/*****");
$testSSRSConnection->Parse();
$testSSRSConnection->TestConnection();
```

Testing  it I get the following error:

```
Usage:TestSSRSConnection.php /server: /report: /uid: /pwd: [/datasource: /uid: /pwd:]
```

Some idea how to go forward in this topic?

**Update**
Doing a `var_export($http_response_header))`

I got

```
array (
      0 => 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized',
      1 => 'Content-Length: 0',
      2 => 'WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate',
      3 => 'WWW-Authenticate: NTLM',
      4 => 'Date: Tue, 04 Mar 2014 22:13:58 GMT',
      5 => 'Connection: close',
)
```

Comment: I would post this on the Discussions or Issues page for that project.

Comment: Seems somehow a little unlikely that the reporting services are set up to respond with a hostname of `192.168.0.1`, can you verify that you are able to access the SOAP service on this URL manually? Also check whether you should be using `https://`

Comment: it's a local ip, as example...The same credentials & link are accessible through browser without problem. But, through SSRS SDK it is not working. I'll try with the `https` options I'm on my way to the office

Comment: @DaveRandom i tried with `https://`, the same result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was with the Authentication Type.

[By default, Reporting Services accepts requests that specify Negotiate and NTLM authentication. If your deployment includes client applications or browsers that use Basic authentication, you must add Basic authentication to the list of supported types.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281309(v=sql.105).aspx)

To get the header response I added in the SSRSReport.php in the line 193

```
if ($content === FALSE) {
  throw new SSRSReportException("", "<br>Failed to connect to Reporting Service  <br/> Make sure   " .
  "that the url ($this->_BaseUrl) and credentials are correct!<br>" .
  var_export($http_response_header));//Line added by me to get the http header response
}
```

Output:

```
array (
   0 => 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized',
   1 => 'Content-Length: 0',
   2 => 'WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate',
   3 => 'WWW-Authenticate: NTLM',
   4 => 'Date: Tue, 04 Mar 2014 22:13:58 GMT',
   5 => 'Connection: close',
)

Failed to connect to Reporting Service
Make sure that the url (http://192.168.0.1/ReportServerURL/) and credentials are correct!
```

---

Adding Basic authentication to the SSRS solve the problem.

**To configure a report server to use Basic authentication**

1- Open RSReportServer.config in a text editor.

2- Find `Authentication`.

3- Copy one of the following XML structures that best fits your needs. The first XML structure provides placeholders for specifying all of the elements, which are described in the next section:

```
<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
         <RSWindowsBasic>
               <LogonMethod>3</LogonMethod>
               <Realm></Realm>
               <DefaultDomain></DefaultDomain>
         </RSWindowsBasic>
    </AuthenticationTypes>
    <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```

If you are using default values, you can copy the minimum element structure:

```
    <AuthenticationTypes>
         <RSWindowsBasic/>
    </AuthenticationTypes>
```

4- Paste it over the existing entries for .

If you are using multiple authentication types, add just the RSWindowsBasic element but do not delete the entries for RSWindowsNegotiate, RSWindowsNTLM, or RSWindowsKerberos.

To support the Safari browser, you cannot configure the report server to use multiple authentication types. You must specify only RSWindowsBasic and delete the other entries.

Note that you cannot use Custom with other authentication types.

5- Replace empty values for  or  with values that are valid for your environment.

6- Save the file.

7- If you configured a scale-out deployment, repeat these steps for other report servers in the deployment.

8- Restart the report server to clear any sessions that are currently open.

Comment: awesome. this was indeed the issue with basic win auth. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there's no actual bug in the SDK, I would venture a guess at saying the problem lies with the constants you have defined:

```
define("UID", "*****\*****");
```

The backslash separates domain from user name in Windows, but it has a special meaning in a string value, e.g.:

```
define("UID", "domain\nick");

echo UID;
```

**Output**

```
domain
nick
```

The `\n` was transformed into a newline; so what you want is escape the backslash:

```
define("UID", "domain\\nick"); // backslash is escaped
echo UID; // output: domain\nick
```

**Update**

Inside `SSRSReport.php` (line 168) there's this:

```
$stream_conext_params = array('http' => array(
    'header' => array($credentials->getBase64Auth())
));
```

However, the `header` context option takes a string, not an array:

```
$stream_conext_params = array('http' => array(
    'header' => $credentials->getBase64Auth(),
));
```

Comment: I tried, but still not working the connect part, I learn something new. thanks

Comment: @EmilioGort Updated the answer, found something else in the code that might be wrong.

Comment: I mean in the same line

Comment: @EmilioGort Okay, here's what I want you to do ... use your browser to get a report and find out the headers sent ... then compare it against the base64 encoded <user>:<password>.

Comment: @EmilioGort Also, can you change the username / password to something you can share with others, such as "bla\\user" and "pwd123" or sth?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48884/discussion-between-emilio-gort-and-jack)